# registering new jQuery after wp_deregister_script() not working

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I have the following in my functions.php and it doesn't seem to load jQuery. If I remove the wp_deregister_script() line it appears to load the wordpress included jQuery and not the one I have manually registered (that I can tell). Anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

```
function register_scripts() {

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js', '1.7', 1);
        wp_register_script('modernizr', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js', 'jquery');    
        wp_register_script('plugins', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/plugins.js', 'jquery', '', 1);    
        wp_register_script('custom', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/script.js', 'jquery', '', 1);

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');
        wp_enqueue_script('plugins');
        wp_enqueue_script('custom');

    }

    add_action('init', 'register_scripts');
```

Comment: It appears to be a load order issue. I think it has been fixed but would be interested if anyone could explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

When setting your dependencies they need to be in an array.

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js', '1.7', 1);
wp_register_script('modernizr', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js', array('jquery') );    
wp_register_script('plugins', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/plugins.js', array('jquery'), '', 1);    
wp_register_script('custom', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/script.js', array( 'jquery') , '', 1);
```

Comment: I don't think they need to be in an array unless you have more than one dependency.